# SQL queries on bookid

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following database schema for a BOOKSTORE database:

```
Books (bookid, title, author, year)
Customers (customerid, name, email)
Purchases (customerid, bookid, year)
Reviews (customerid, bookid, rating)
Pricing (bookid, format, price)
```

Ive got this question:

Find the ratings information (show titles, authors and average ratings) for books on 'CIVIL WAR' (i.e., title contains 'CIVIL WAR').

And what ive got so far is:

```
SELECT title, author, AVG(r1.rating)
FROM Books, Reviews
WHERE title LIKE '%CIVIL WAR%'
```

but its wrong :( 
any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: AND books.bookid = reviews.bookid

Comment: You also need a group by clause.  And an alias for reviews.

Comment: What are you getting? What is wrong? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

This follows the structure you give:

```
SELECT books.title, books.author, AVG(reviews.rating)
  FROM books, reviews
 WHERE books.bookid = reviews.bookid 
   AND books.title LIKE '%CIVIL WAR%'
GROUP BY books.title, books.author
```

You could also consider using a `JOIN` rather than doing the join in the `WHERE` clause as I do that would be:

```
FROM books
JOIN reviews ON reviews.bookid = books.bookid
```

Also, consider using an alias for the tables, as that will shorten the more complex queries:

```
FROM `Books b` 

--Will enable you to write 
 AND b.title LIKE '%CIVIL WAR%'
```

Comment: Shouldn't you drop the `r1.`?

Comment: `GROUP BY books.bookid, title, author` It's unlikely that an author has published two books with same title but if there is one, it will mess your results.

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej You are right. Updated the query to be fully qualified.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! sorry im a new user i cant upvote ur answer yet :( thank you though

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT B.title, B.author, AVG(R.rating) Avg_Rating
FROM Books B
  JOIN Reviews R
   ON B.bookid = R.bookid
WHERE B.title LIKE '%CIVIL WAR%'
GROUP BY B.title, B.author
```

If you have more than one title/author you can group by bookid also.

```
SELECT B.title, B.author, AVG(R.rating) Avg_Rating
FROM Books B
  JOIN Reviews R
   ON B.bookid = R.bookid
WHERE B.title LIKE '%CIVIL WAR%'
GROUP BY B.bookid, B.title, B.author
```